# std::enable_if_t doesn't match partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++17, template-specialization, partial-specialization

If my understanding is correct, alias templates are actually templates and hence can be passed as arguments where a class template is expected. Which is what makes the following code valid -

```
template <template <bool, typename> T>
struct foo {};

foo<std::enable_if_t> x;
```

It is also possible to use partial specialization to match template classes. Which is why the following code prints "Version 2".

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    static void print() {std::cout << "Version 1" << std::endl;}
};

template <template <typename> typename T, typename X>
struct foo<T<X>> {
    static void print() {std::cout << "Version 2" << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T>
struct bar {

};
...
foo<bar<int>>::print();
```

Now my question is, why doesn't the following code print "Version 2", but instead prints "Version 1"

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    static void print() {std::cout << "Version 1" << std::endl;}    
};


template <template <bool, typename> typename T, bool X, typename Y>
struct foo<T<X, Y>> {
    static void print() {std::cout << "Version 2" << std::endl;}
};

foo<std::enable_if_t<true, int>>::print();
```

Shouldn't the second partial specialization be a better match where T=std::enable_if_t, X=true, Y=int?

Answer (score 3):

As expected, the following prints "Version 2"

```
foo<std::enable_if<true, int>>::print();
```

In your example however, the type `std::enable_if_t<true, int>` is equivalent to `int` and cannot match cannot match `T<X, Y>`.

cppreference explains it [like this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

> An alias template is a template which, when specialized, is equivalent to the result of substituting the template arguments of the alias template for the template parameters in the *type-id*

The alias `std::enable_if_t` can match `template <bool, typename> typename`, but once specialized it cannot be deconstructed.

Comment: I understand why the example you provided would match the partial specialization. Obviously `std::enable_if` is an _entirely_ different type. I think what I am wondering about the last statement in your answer - '"The alias std::enable_if_t can match template <bool, typename> typename, but once specialized it cannot be deconstructed." -- why? Is there a language in the standard that elaborates on this?

Comment: Though, your answer is definitely helpful in understanding what is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an alias template has arguments, it is immediately replaced with the type it aliases. So, for example, `std::enable_if_t<true, int>` is immediately replaced by `int`. This applies even in a dependent context; so for example if you have a function like this:

```
template <bool b, typename T>
void foo(std::enable_if_t<b, T>);
```

the compiler rewrites it to:

```
template <bool b, typename T>
void foo(typename std::enable_if<b, T>::type);
```

The original alias has disappeared from the equation.

It follows that a type like `T<X, Y>` can't be used to deduce `T` as an alias template because whatever type `U` is provided for `T<X, Y>` to match against, if it originally had the form `A<X, Y>` for some alias template `A`, it would have been replaced by whatever that alias template aliases to, and `A` would no longer be present. (However, an alias template can be deduced as an *argument* of a class template that has a template template parameter, since an alias template can be a valid template template argument)

Comment: I see, would it be right to say that the partial specialization written in the last example matches "template classes". While an alias template is a template, it doesn't produce a template class (or type) after substitution but the actual type it aliases?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It produces whatever type it aliases, which may or may not be a class template specialization itself.